# Sorting the output of ps does not work

Tags: linux, sort, ps

I want to sort the output of [the following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910155/69537) based on `pcpu`:

```
ps -p 29492 -L -o pid,tid,psr,pcpu
```

I tried the following:

```
ps -p 29492 -L -o pid,tid,psr,pcpu --sort=pcpu
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely that in your implementation of `ps`, sorting only applies to processes, not threads (see [`fancy_spew()` in `procps`' `display.c`](http://sources.debian.net/src/procps/2:3.3.10-4/ps/display.c/#L539)). As far as I can tell, if you want to sort threads you need to post-process the output; e.g.

```
ps -p 29492 -L -o pid,tid,psr,pcpu | sort -n -k4,4
```

but then the header line gets mixed up in the output. If you want to keep the header line, you can pull it out and print it separately:

```
ps -p 29492 -L -o pid,tid,psr,pcpu | sed -e1\!b -e'w /dev/fd/2' -ed | sort -n -k4,4
```

You can also simply drop the header line by specifying blank header values for all the output selectors:

```
ps -p 29492 -L -o pid=,tid=,psr=,pcpu= | sort -n -k4,4
```

In all these cases, you can reverse the sort by adding `-r` to the `sort` parameters. The sort order may be affected by `LC_NUMERIC` or `LC_ALL`; setting `LC_ALL=C` will sort values with a decimal point `.` correctly.